# Как сгруппировать данные по колонкам таблицы со схожими параметрами?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

Есть таблица с двумя колонками:

1. account
2. currency

Как написать запрос в *MS Sql*, чтобы сгруппировать account по currency?

Например, есть 3 валюты. Запрос должен вернуть таблицу с тремя колонками с названием валюты (column_name) и счета которые соответствуют к определенным валютам.

P.S. В запросе нельзя указывать какие именно валюты есть, запрос должен сам автоматически распределить счета по существующим валютам и назначить колонке имя валюты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите структуру таблиц, то что уже пытились написать, это существенно ускорит процесс

Comment: Похоже, Вы хотите dynamic pivot - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803483/pivot-with-an-indefinite-amount-of-distinct-values

Comment: приложил структуру

Comment: "Сам автоматом" только динамикой, как вам предложили выше. других путей не существует

Comment: всем спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(в картинках ибо sql строки на сайте не корректно будут отображаться) 
Вариант для MySql. Реализация MsSQL под вопросом ибо не в курсе. 
Запрос динамически определяет поля и на их основе строит запрос.
Реализация в 3 запроса SELECT. 1 и 2 запрос  записывают данные в переменные. 1 запрос чтобы знать имя первой колонки для where. 
 2-й запрос формирует данные для 3-го sql запроса. Данные формируются через group_concat - тоже что и concat но в дополнение обьеденяет и строки в одну большую строку. 
 3-й запрос разбит на concat prepare и execute. ток так можно применить переменные для построения запроса.

На скорость не оценивалось. Да и сомневаюсь что будет производительней.
Намног производительней если знаешь что запрашиваешь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Принцип реализации 3 запроса можн разобрать на примере: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В MySQl такой формат написания соответствует INNER JOIN.
Если в MSSql тоже самое и отрабатывает group_concat, и может отрабатывать запросы в переменные, то возможно сработает и в MSsql.
И на Заметку - каждое новое динамическое поле в колонке field  - это добавление нового JOIN в обработке. Т.е. если 10 полей то 10 JOIN - как обьединения 10-ти страниц.
Туже реализацию можно наложить на PIVOT. Первый запрос определяет данные для запроса а 2-й через pivot формирует вертикальные данные в горизонтальное представление.

---

Дополню. Пересмотрел решение и создал более оптимальный запрос.
Исключил JOIN  и попросту через GROUP_CONCAT +ORDER_BY горизонтально развернул. также в 2 запроса принцип тот же.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]